# Bash script variables

Tags: macos, bash

I need to write a script that would take two filenames as arguments, then remove all duplicate slashes from those and pass them into some other app, let's say vim.

I started with something like that but of course it doesn't work

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/local/bin/vim $($1 | sed s#//*#/#g)
```

Comment: Remove duplicate slashes from file names or files?

Comment: ...and why would you care about removing duplicate slashes from the name? A filename starting with `//` _may_ be given special treatment if the local OS or filesystem chooses to do so, but anywhere other than in the leading position extra slashes are harmless on any POSIX-compliant system.

Comment: Also, this code creates bugs when handed filenames with spaces.

Comment: the original problem is that SourceTree doesn't pass $LOCAL file when configured to use vim as differ, I noticed that for whatever reason it has double slash in the end, but removing slashes didn't solve my problem :( So SourceTree sends filepath that looks like that  `/var/folders/lk/p5gtdm514773pg4ldm5whf1w0000gn/T//lVM4Zx_build-server-task.coffee` any other editor can open that, but vim just refuses

Answer (score 2):

The pipe operator will take the output of one command and pass it to another command.  In your case, `$1` is a string value that you don't want to run as a command.  Instead you can pass that value into `sed` with the string redirection operator `<<<`, as follows:

```
$(sed s#//*#/#g <<< $1)
```

Comment: Is the `<<<` specific to Bash or is it available in a POSIX shell too?

Comment: @dreamlax, it's a bashism.

Comment: ...the POSIX equivalent would be `<<EOF`, followed by a newline, then `$1`, then another newline, then `EOF`. Obviously, using `<<<` is shorter.

Answer (score 1):

Give [readlink](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?readlink) a try:

```
/usr/local/bin/vim "$(readlink -m "$1")"
```

Comment: @Agzam, "doesn't work" is not enough information to actually understand or diagnose a problem. If you want to provide something helpful, use `#!/bin/bash -x` as the shebang for your script so you can show the command it actually runs, and how this differs from what you expect or desire.

Comment: @Agzam, ...the most likely reason this wouldn't work, by the way, would be being on an operating system with a non-GNU implementation of `readlink`. Did you specify your OS in the question? [Edit: Ahh, yes, you did -- Apple, which indeed uses a BSD readlink rather than a GNU one].

Comment: @Agzam: For files that already exist, this will work on OS X if you simply take out the `-m`; for files that don't exist, you'll need to find a different solution. Of course, you could also install GNU readlink in your PATH before the system one, and that would fix it too.